# How to resize NSCollectionView based on its largest child's size?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, autolayout

I am trying to show a NSCollectionView inside a NSPopover, like so:

[image]

Problem is that I am not able to resize NSCollectionView/NSPopover to fit the content of the NSCollectionViewItem. Either the text in label gets compressed like above or overlaps with the button.

Disclaimer: I am new to xcode/cocoa domain.

Comment: How do you set current NSPopover size?

Comment: I don't, I guess whatever is set by auto layout ? is there anyway to make it dynamic or is it that I have to set it programmatically after I know whats to be shown ?

Comment: If it is set by autolayout, just set the constraints right way. Did you?

Comment: Ok I didn't apply any constraints to the popover, how can I apply constraints such that it expands horizontally ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you need to apply proper constraints only to your NSCollectionViewItem-child class.

```
+--------------------------+ 
|      |           |       |
|      5           5       |
|      |           |       |
|-5-[label]-10-[button]-10-|
|               <-40->     |
+--------------------------+
```

Because of label using default intrinsic size, it'll aim to be as wide as it's contents requires.

But be aware of too wide label. In this case your NSPopover will be wide as well. Apply to label width constraint with relation property of "<=" and defined max width constant.

Comment: These are the constraints that I previously set on collectionViewItem's views:  http://i.imgur.com/HLdslsK.png  can you point out which part is incorrect ?

Comment: Your picture is not enough to find out unfortunately. Look at edited answer.

Comment: So I have constrains setup almost like you mentioned, snapped label to left edge of superview, button to right edge, fixed width to button & constraint between label & button. If I increase width of collection view in auto layout, it seem to reflect at runtime.

Comment: I am also doing var minSize = NSMakeSize(0, 20); collectionView.maxItemSize = minSize; while updating the collection view.